# Have problem is fetching all users. Apollo-Server-Express-Sequelize-GetAllUsers

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I am trying to implement signup, signin, getcurrentuser, getallusers functionalities.

except getllusers everything is working fine.

I have used JWT Token verification

help me out to find, how to query all users if a user is logged in

Resolvers

```
const { ApolloError, AuthenticationError } = require("apollo-server-express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { generateToken } = require("../utils/index");

module.exports = {
  Query: {
    me(parent, args, { models, authUser }) {
      return models.User.findByPk(authUser.id);
    },

    getAllUsers: async (parent, args, { models }) => {
      const allUsers = await models.User.findAll();
      console.log(allUsers);
      return allUsers;
    },
    users: async (parent, args, { models }) => {
      await models.User.findAll();
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    async signUp(parent, { username, email, password }, { models }) {
      const userExists = await models.User.findOne({ where: { email } });

      if (userExists) {
        throw new ApolloError("Email is already in use");
      }
      const user = await models.User.create({ username, email, password });

      //   ?console.log(token);

      return { token: generateToken(user) };
    },
    async signIn(parent, { email, password }, context) {
      const user = await context.models.User.findOne({ where: { email } });
      if (!user) {
        throw new AuthenticationError("Invalid Email");
      }
      const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!isPasswordValid) {
        throw new AuthenticationError("Invalid Password");
      }
      return { token: generateToken(user) };
    },
    // async signIn(parent, { email, password }, { models }) {
    //   const user = await models.User.findOne({ where: { email } });
    //   if (!user) {
    //     throw new AuthenticationError("Invalid Email");
    //   }
    //   const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    //   if (!isPasswordValid) {
    //     throw new AuthenticationError("Invalid Password");
    //   }
    //   return { token: generateToken(user) };
    // },
  },
};
```

Type Defs

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server-express");
module.exports = gql`
  type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    email: String!
    role: Role!
    avatar: String
    createdAt: DateTime!
    updatedAt: DateTime!
  }

  enum Role {
    ADMIN
    USER
  }
  type Token {
    token: String!
  }
  extend type Mutation {
    signUp(username: String!, email: String!, password: String!): Token!
    signIn(email: String!, password: String!): Token!
  }

  extend type Query {
    getAllUsers: User
    users: User
    me: User!
  }
`;
```

Here is my Index.JS file

My Headers

```
const express = require("express");
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server-express");
const models = require("./models");
const typeDefs = require("./typedefs");
const resolvers = require("./resolvers");
const { getAuthUser } = require("./utils");
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
```

Server Initializaation

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => {
    const authUser = getAuthUser(req);
    console.log("Auth User", authUser);
    return { models, authUser };
  },
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: true })   
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`started at ${port} ${server.graphqlPath}`));
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.username.",  but console.log prints all users just fine

Comment: Can you check in a DB all user's usernames if some of them is null?

Comment: have only 3 users.. all usernames are full